# Where's located JIRA cloud's datacener?

Tags: bitbucket, jira, confluence, jira-plugin, jira-rest-java-api

I'm wondering if Atlassian has a public data-center (for JIRA, Confluence and BitBucket) in **Europe**.

It seems like they have in the US only.
Do you know about?

Answer (score 1):

They do not. They are only hosted in the US. Go to [this site](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/CLOUD-3635) to vote on regional datacenters and to remain informed on the issue.